# AWS RDS MSSQL performance recommendations

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[image: cloudwatch data]
I am currently running MSSQL on AWS RDS t2.medium with 100 GB storage (8GB used).
100 GB has a base 300 IOPS, but I'm not sure why my read IOPS is so slow even though it is under 300.

To query something it took about 5 - 15 seconds.

Talking about memory, every time i upgrade the instance, the freeable memory always left 2xx MB. I googled and searched, apparently all the memory is use to cache.

Any suggestion how to improve the performance by looking at my monitor?

a) Should I upgrade my instance ? MY CPU usage is very low. If yes, what do you recommend? High memory? Or SSD? Or High CPU? 
b) Or should I increase storage size? 
c) Or should I go with provisioned IOPS?

Comment: Personally, whenever I'm having trouble with performance in a database, the most fruitful place to look is usually the indexes. If your machine is capable of 300 IOPS per second, and a query was taking 5 seconds, if it was maxing out it's throughput to the drive, that would be 1500 Operations, which depending on your dataset might indicate a table scan. A proper index with a query that yields a small subset of the data should be much faster.

Comment: Add your table create command(s) to the question along with an example query

Comment: Running the query on a local machine with SQL Server install take only 1 sec.But with RDS it took 5 sec